# Prove that: Any field containing $Z[i]$ as a subring contains $Q[i]$ as a subfield.

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, gaussian-integers

My question is

Prove that: Any field containing $Z[i]$ as a subring contains $Q[i]$ as a subfield.

I don't know how to prove this question.
Please if someone could prove it for me.

It seems when I asked this question before it was not clear enough so a direct approach.
If you'll still find my question inappropriate then please tell me how to frame one.
I would really like the added help. Thank you.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is the smallest field containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and $i$.  $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is the smallest ring containing  $\mathbb{Z}$ and $i$. If a field contains $\mathbb{Z}$ then ...

Comment: It might seem "efficient" just to state the problem in the title and refer thereafter to it in the body of the Question, but this invites confusion.  There is no actual "question" clearly stated.  Please edit the body of the Question to give a fairly self-contained problem statement.

Comment: @hardmathThis doesn't invite confusion... It means a student read through the textbook found a question and wanted to prove why the statement is true. And for that there is a proof required. Which I do not know how to prove.

Comment: Please add your own thought/attempts to the question. Without this, it is hard to  judge at what level to answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

Let $F$ be a field which contains the integers $a$ and $b$ with $b\ne 0$. Then by definition of a field $F$ also contains $1/b$, hence contains $a/b$. So any field which contains $\mathbb Z$ also contains $\mathbb Q$.

It follows that if $F$ contains $\mathbb Z$ and $i$ then $F$ contains $\mathbb Q$ and $i$, hence contains $\mathbb Q(i)$.